# Transformar imagem em um array de bytes

Tags: android, imageview

```
ImageView imgProduto = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgProduto);

Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable)imgProduto.getDrawable()).getBitmap();
                ByteArrayOutputStream saida = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100,saida);
                final byte[] img = saida.toByteArray();
                produto.setFoto(img);
```

Comment: Qual é a dúvida?

Comment: usei este código para converter uma imagem em um array de bytes mas ao mandar para o banco de dados pelo produto.setFoto(img) não salvou

Comment: Qual banco está usando? É local ou remoto? Está usando algum ORM para acesso ao banco?

Comment: Estou usando o MYSQL Local com um Web Service REST em Java